# Create Reusable HTTP Interceptor Library Angular

Tags: angular, shared-libraries

I have multiple angular apps that use an HTTP Interceptor. I would like to be able to SHARE a single interceptor among all of the apps vs duplicating the same interceptor multiple times. I have a component library with which we have multiple shared components that are used in the angular apps, but not sure how to implement an interceptor across an entire app from a shared library.

What i need it direction about creating a shared HTTP Interceptor that is loaded from a library.

Comment: Angular cli has a way of creating libraries.  https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: I have an existing library, but my question still is how to implement an interceptor as typically they are imported into the app module. What does that import look like when importing from a library?